# How java actually prints on screen

Tags: java, printing, jvm

I'm new to java and learning java from official java documentation from oracle. In most of the program example provided by java documentation, `system.out.println(...)` statement is used to print the text or message on the screen. There are also some other method like `print(), printf() etc` for writing on screen.

I want to know how actually these methods works. I take a look on source of these methods and going into deep, I found that finally `write(char cbuf[], int off, int len)` method is called in every print method (directly or indirectly), and this method is abstract.

So how JVM print/write something on screen. According to me, it is internal working of JVM . JVM search for a display window and call system commands of OS, for example `echo` in linux and windows OS.

Am I right, if not then explain the working of these methods and correct me.

Comment: You had the right idea.  It's your code that eventually calls the operating system routines to write to the screen, not the JVM.

Answer (score 3):

Taking a look at the source for OpenJDK, there is a method at [java.lang.System:254](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/lang/System.java?av=f#254) that appears to set the `System.out` `PrintStream` value, which is called later at [java.lang.System:1144](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/lang/System.java#1144).

```
 254:  private static native void  [More ...] setOut0(PrintStream out);

1144:  setOut0(new PrintStream(new BufferedOutputStream(fdOut, 128), true));
```

`fdOut` is a reference to a `FileOutputStream` set at [java.lang.System:1141](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/lang/System.java?av=f#1141),

```
1141:  FileOutputStream fdOut = new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out);
```

And the `FileDescriptor.out` is

> handle to the standard output stream. Usually, this file descriptor is not used directly, but rather via the output stream known as `System.out`.

So how does a `PrintStream` handle methods like `print()`? (You probably see where I'm going to go here.

At [java.io.PrintStream:582-584](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/io/PrintStream.java#PrintStream.print%28char%29) is the `print(char c)` method,

```
 582:  public void print(char c) {
 583:      write(String.valueOf(c));
 584:  }
```

`write()` in turn writes the value passed and flushes the output stream passed to `PrintStream()`.

The remaining bits of implementation are native methods, which by definition vary based upon the platform and invocation of the program. They could be anything from the console screen to a printer, or an orbital laser burning the output onto the Earth's surface.

Humor aside, I hope that helps in understanding.